# My content overflow won't scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I recently made my website dynamic and everything was working until the content overflow on the home page wouldn't allow me to scroll to the bottom of the content. Here's a link to my site => http://www.epic-penguin.com

Comment: Show code here. Don't link. I don't have time to search for relevant code in your source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `position:fixed` from the `div#top` brings back the scrollbar, but it leaves the site fairly borked.

On a side note - there's really no need to use `frame`s any more. `divs` with fixed heights and `overflow-y` set to scroll do pretty much the same thing in a way that's better for accessibility and maybe SEO.